# (mac) Can I run Microsoft Edge in Selenium without having the browser installed on my pc?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, selenium

I'm woking on a selendium and airflow project for bing rewards and I'm hoping I don't have to install Microsoft edge as my computer is always running out of space. Does anyone know off hand if it's possible to make Selenium scripts for a driver if you dont have the dmg installed on your computer?

Comment: Try to copy the browser installed folder in your machine to some project folder and set system property path to the launcher file in that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that using **RemoteWebDriver**.

but make sure your remote device, cloud etc must have that respective browser which is pointed by RemoteWebDriver.

Refer below:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver

Example code:

https://gist.github.com/djangofan/4127074